# Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error" on new actions created

Tags: symfony-1.4

I get the error as soon as I enter one of my actions on the project.

> Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error". Something is broken

Only on 1 page (Action) it happens. The most recent Action I created. The strange thing is that this happens only on the server. Locally on my windows server the page works normally.

The PHP internal logs on the server returns no errors.

The error occurs even if I remove all the code in the action and even if I clear the cache with 'php symfony cc'. Even if I set the permissions with 'php symfony project:permissions'. Even if I combine all of the previous solutions in different order.

Here is the action code:

```
  public function executeExportPostsToProject(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    echo 'why?? Show me please!';
  }
```

On the same module there are about 20 other actions decleared the same way. I'm going crazy.

Tryed to check my server configuration for symfony. No Warnings.
The symfony version is 1.4.5.

Comment: Are you working on development environment (backed/frontend_dev.php)? You should see the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the file name of the View is case sensitive under Linux. On Windows hadn't the same problem. On Linux for some reasons with the new files created on windows the problem occured. I renamed the View from exportPostsToProject.php to ExportPostsToProject.php solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

add route like this in your routing.yml for this action:

```
route_name:
  url:  /route-name-example
  param:  { module: ModuleName, action: exportPostsToProject }
```

and make sure to be on DEV environment